# Views date range filter adds weird condition

Tags: views, 8

I have a view for a content type. This content type has a date field (only date) and I have added and exposed a filter for this field ("date is between" option). 
I have added and exposed a filter for other text field.
If I put a condition on the text field in the filter of the view, then it generate a weird SQL for the date field.

```
SELECT node_field_data.nid AS nid, node_field_data_node__field_liq_club.nid AS node_field_data_node__field_liq_club_nid
FROM
node_field_data node_field_data
LEFT JOIN node__field_liq_club node__field_liq_club ON node_field_data.nid = node__field_liq_club.entity_id AND node__field_liq_club.deleted = '0'
INNER JOIN node_field_data node_field_data_node__field_liq_club ON node__field_liq_club.field_liq_club_target_id = node_field_data_node__field_liq_club.nid
LEFT JOIN node__field_liq_ejercicio node__field_liq_ejercicio ON node_field_data.nid = node__field_liq_ejercicio.entity_id AND node__field_liq_ejercicio.deleted = '0'
LEFT JOIN node__field_liq_fechaliq node__field_liq_fechaliq ON node_field_data.nid = node__field_liq_fechaliq.entity_id AND node__field_liq_fechaliq.deleted = '0'
LEFT JOIN node__field_liq_fechapago node__field_liq_fechapago ON node_field_data.nid = node__field_liq_fechapago.entity_id AND node__field_liq_fechapago.deleted = '0'
WHERE
(node_field_data.status = '1') AND (node_field_data.type IN ('liquidacion')) AND (node__field_liq_ejercicio.field_liq_ejercicio_value = '2010') AND 
((DATE_FORMAT(node__field_liq_fechaliq.field_liq_fechaliq_value, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT('2019-01-01T00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d') AND DATE_FORMAT('2019-12-31T00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d'))) 
AND ((DATE_FORMAT((node__field_liq_fechapago.field_liq_fechapago_value + INTERVAL 7200 SECOND), '%Y-%m-%d\T%H:%i:%s') BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(('2018-12-31T23:00:00' + INTERVAL 7200 SECOND), '%Y-%m-%d\T%H:%i:%s') AND DATE_FORMAT(('2019-12-30T23:00:00' + INTERVAL 7200 SECOND), '%Y-%m-%d\T%H:%i:%s')))
LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0
```

My text field add the condition:
`node__field_liq_ejercicio.field_liq_ejercicio_value = '2010'`

But, although I don't fill any condition for date-range, it adds:

```
    and ((DATE_FORMAT(node__field_liq_fechaliq.field_liq_fechaliq_value, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT('2019-01-01T00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d') AND DATE_FORMAT('2019-12-31T00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d'))) 
AND ((DATE_FORMAT((node__field_liq_fechapago.field_liq_fechapago_value + INTERVAL 7200 SECOND), '%Y-%m-%d\T%H:%i:%s') BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(('2018-12-31T23:00:00' + INTERVAL 7200 SECOND), '%Y-%m-%d\T%H:%i:%s') AND DATE_FORMAT(('2019-12-30T23:00:00' + INTERVAL 7200 SECOND), '%Y-%m-%d\T%H:%i:%s')))
```

I don't know why it is added, and how to solve this issue. Why this INTERVAL 7200 SECOND?. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some test I have found that a module was changing filter form states, and then the filter fields were wrong when the query were constructed. I fix that and now it works good.