# How to know what is changing views sql query?

Tags: views, 8

I would like to know what modules are altering the select sql of a view. Is there any way I could know it?. Due to [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/285095/views-date-range-filter-adds-weird-condition) I put some days ago, I would like to find why that sql is altered. I have read views core files (core/modules/views/src/Plugin/views/filter/Date.php) but this file isn't adding what I was searching for.

Comment: You could simply disable modules one by one until you got your candidate. Asking for a list of modules that possibly may alter SQL queries probably is too broad to ever be answered precisely.

Comment: You can search in your project for `_views_query_alter` and find all modules implementing views query alter. Then you just have to look which of then are altering your specific view.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I did without success

Comment: But i didn't find what is changing the query. I don't know what is happening.

Comment: I finally found that a module was changing the form filter states and then, the query was wrong from its origin.